# switch array object for ArrayAdapter dynamically?

Tags: android, adapter

I know I can update the array which was initally passed to the arrayAdapter's constructor, and call notifyDataSetChanged.

I wonder if it's possible to plug-in new arraylist into adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple:

```
  mAdapter.clear();
  mAdapter.addAll(collection);
```

also, do add individual elements you can call `mAdapter.add(element);` instead of having to keep a reference to the Array that was passed to the constructor.